# How to pass arguments to an ASP .NET Core application from the WIndows service that hosts it

Tags: c#, windows-services, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

I created an ASP .NET Core 2.1 application hosted in a Windows Service, following this guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/windows-service?view=aspnetcore-2.1

When I start the windows service I pass programmatically the IP Port as argument because I want to change the applicationUrl used into the launchsettings.json.

Below I report the code where I start the service

```
ServiceController controller = ...;
// Do something
args = new string[]{8080};
controller.Start(args);
```

Into my ASP .Net Core project I have a CustomWebHostService class where I get the previous argument in the OnStarting() method.

```
public class CustomWebHostService : WebHostService
{
    ////private Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILogger _logger;

    /// <summary>
    /// The <see cref="Logger"/> object
    /// </summary>
    private static Logger _logger;

    public CustomWebHostService(IWebHost host) : base(host)
    {
        ////_logger = host.Services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<CustomWebHostService>>();

        _logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    }

    protected override void OnStarting(string[] args)
    {
        ////_logger.LogDebug("OnStarting method called.");
        _logger.Info("OnStarting method called.");

        // TODO Change launchsettings with the IP Port


        base.OnStarting(args);
    }

    protected override void OnStarted()
    {
        ////_logger.LogDebug("OnStarted method called.");
        _logger.Info("OnStarted method called.");

        base.OnStarted();
    }

    protected override void OnStopping()
    {
        ////_logger.LogDebug("OnStopping method called.");
        _logger.Info("OnStopping method called.");

        base.OnStopping();
    }
}
```

Now I should pass this argument to my builder (IWebHostBuilder interface) and to updated my configuration.

```
builder.UseUrls(String.Format("http://*:{0};http://localhost:{0}", myPort));
```

How can I do?

Thanks.